# mem_func and virtual function

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have the following classes:

```
 class A
{
   public:
        virtual void myfunc(unsigned char c, std::string* dest) = 0;
};

   class B : public class A
{
    public:
        virtual void myfunc(unsigned char c, std::string* dest);
};

void someOtherFunc(const std::string& str,A *pointerFunc)
{
    std::string tmp;
        for_each(str.begin(),
                 str.end(),                 
                 std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun(pointerFunc->myfunc), &tmp));
}
```

I get the following compilation error:
 error: no matching function for call to \u2018mem_fun()\u2019

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You're looking for `std::mem_fun(&A::myfunc)`.</s>

EDIT: You can't use `mem_fun` at all here -- no overload of `mem_fun` allows you to make a two argument member function into a functor. You're going to have to use something like `boost::bind`/`std::tr1::bind` (If you have TR1)/`std::bind` (If you have C++0x) or you're going to have to write your own functor.

Note that even if `mem_fun` was able to do this sort of binding, then `std::bind2nd` would fail, because `bind2nd` expects a functor taking two arguments, and binding a member function pointer like this is going to produce a functor with three arguments.

You have a few ways around this:

1. Write your own functor that does what you want.
2. Write an explicit loop instead of `std::for_each`.
3. One of the not-yet-standard binder functions I mentioned above (and demonstrated in @David's answer)
4. Don't bother with the virtual function in the first place -- make your method accept a plain function pointer and implement things in terms of the function pointer. Of course this only works if `myfunc` doesn't depend on members of the class to which it belongs (in which case it shouldn't have ever been put into a class in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to use here is use a [pointer to a member function](http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html) to apply a member function of another object to every object in the container.  Apparently none of the adapters will work in this case.  In that case the only solution is to write a special wrapper functor class for it.

Comment: Of course. I forgot to type the *pointerFunc in the code. I still get the same compilation error. can I use mem_fun on a virtual function?

Comment: `ptr_fun` cannot convert a member function pointer into a functor. None of the adapters are going to work for @Tal's case here -- there are overloads of `mem_fun` which will work with single argument member functions, but not two argument member functions (to say nothing of the fact that binding a 2 arg member function would produce a 3 arg functor which would cause `std::bind2nd` not to work either)

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration does not represent what you want to do.

try:

```
void someOtherFunc(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string tmp;

    B BInstance;
    A* ptrToB = &BInstance;


    for_each(str.begin(),
        str.end(),                 
        boost::bind(&A::myfunc, ptrToB, _1, &tmp));
}
```

this (or a variation of) should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation behind of std::mem_fun you should be able to write your own:

EDIT (made it "human-readable")

```
template<class Result, class Ty, class Arg>
class mem_fun1_t : public binary_function<Ty*, Arg, Result>
{
private:
 Result (Ty::*m_mf)(Arg);

public:
 mem_fun1_t(Result (Ty::*mf)(Arg)) : m_mf(mf) { }

 Result operator()(Ty* pLeft, Arg Right) const {
  return ((pLleft->*m_mf)(Right));
 }
};
```